# How do I show text instead of id for selected value in show.html in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

I created a drop down box in my form using select_tag:

```
<%= select_tag(:warning, options_for_select([['None', 1], ['Medium', 2], ['High', 3]], 1)) %>
```

Now I want to display the corresponding text for the value they select rather than the id in my show.html.erb, so it displays 'None' instead of 1.  I am new to this and can't quite figure it out.  Right now I am just using the default scaffold code and that displays the id:

```
<%= @standing.warning %>
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Have you tried inverting the options so that `['None', 1]` becomes `[1, 'None']`?</strike>

Update your Standing model:

```
class Standing
  @@warning_labels = { 1 => 'None', 2 => 'Medium', 3 => 'High' }

  def warning_str
    @@warning_labels[@warning]
  end
end
```

In show.rb:

```
<%= @standing.warning_str %>
```

**OR**

In your `standing_helpers.rb`:

```
def warning_str(warning_id)
  warning_labels = { 1 => 'None', 2 => 'Medium', 3 => 'High' }
  warning_labels[warning_id];
end
```

In show.rb:

```
<%= warning_str(@standing.warning) %>
```

Comment: The form works great.  What I am trying to do is make the index.html.erb and show.html.erb display the text instead of the number, and I am not even sure where to begin.  Searches aren't turning up much.

Comment: @Rob Sorry, misread that as your `<selects>` where showing numbers instead of names

Comment: Oh no problem. I just hate when something this simple seems so hard when you are first learning :)

Comment: You should add that info to your model, which I assumed was called `Standing`.  If that is indeed the name of your model, it will be in `apps/models/standing.rb`

Comment: Awesome!  This definitely appears to work, but I just discovered that no matter what I select on my NEW or EDIT forms, it's not updating the record.  It's always 1 no matter what I do.  Should I post that as another question?

Comment: @Rob I would make a second question, yes.